# MySQL Cluster NDB API Events Node Failure

Tags: mysql, mysql-cluster

After sifting through the NDB API Events documentation and class comments, I came across this comment in  NdbEventOperation.hpp:

`/*
* Known Issues: 
* - If a node failure has occured not all events will be recieved
*   anymore. Drop NdbEventOperation and Create again after nodes are up
*   again. Will be fixed in later versions
*/`

Does this mean if a **Data** node fails, NDB Events will not be received?

I have tested killing a data node while I'm running my NDB API Event listener program, and I am still receiving all events(I only have 2 events right now during prototyping).

**Update:**

Here's some more clarification:

Say, for example, we have a cluster of four hosts(n1, n2, n3, n4), with two data nodes(n1, n2), and 1 Management Node(n3), and one two SQL Nodes(n3, n4). So, if a Data node goes down(say n1), I would imagine those Events that were handled by n1, will now be handled by n2, since Cluster Events happen synchronously. So, I don't see how we would lose any of these Events.

I'm wondering if the comment in NdbEventOperation.hpp refers to a Data Node, a Management Node, or a SQL Node.

I'm also wondering if this issue has been fixed(since it says in the comments that "it will be fixed in later versions").

**This comment in NdbEventOperation.hpp looks really bad, since the whole concept of a MySQL Cluster revolves around availability and Events. I have trouble believing that some events will not be received if a Data node goes down in a cluster.**